# SVN on a server without SSH, possible?

Tags: svn, ssh, hosting

My hosting (shared) doesn't provide any SSH access (and doesn't plan to).

Is there a way I can make a SVN server on it?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can run the svn server [with the svnserve protocol](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.serverconfig.svnserve.html) without SSH.

Also, you can have Apache use the svn_dav plugin to provide [SVN access via HTTP](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.serverconfig.httpd.html) without the HTTPS.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but I'm not sure to understand how I will be able to run SVN without SSH access?

Comment: @guylabbe.ca Well, you can follow the instructions detailed in setting up the svnserve protocol (the first link) or you can follow the instructions detailed in setting up HTTP access (the second link).  If by needing SSH you mean you cannot get into the machine to do either setup, how did you intend to install on a machine you cannot enter?

Comment: I have only access to cPanel and FTP. Then I understand I can't do anything :( thanks for your help, I should have precised I don't have access to command line

Comment: What you need is VPS hosting.  Basically you get your own virtual machine, which you can install anything on it.  You will get full root / Administrator access; because, it's your own private virtual machine.

Comment: Damn, I will need one of those ... I just migrated all my websites to a reselling account with a WHM access but no right to configure anything ...

Comment: Sharing a website is a good way to keep costs down, but it means nobody really gets root access.  Others don't want you to have it (to snoop at their stuff) and you don't want others to have it (to snoop at your stuff).  VPS costs more; because, you don't share that virtual machine with anything.  The upside is that you can install anything, configure anything, do anything (the downside is that you are on the hook for all OS maintenance).

Comment: @EdwinBuck I don't have SSH and also don't have access to httpd.conf file because I'm on shared hosting, how can I setup SVN with these restrictions, please reply. Thanks

Comment: @TahirYasin Contact the real system administrator of that machine.  Also be prepared to hear that you might need to pay more for such services.  If you rent, you don't own, and you might not be able to do everything you want to do.

Answer (score 1):

There are ways to set up SVN so that it doesn't need SSH (it wouldn't be secured though). However, you will need access (typically using SSH) to the machine in order to setup SVN this way. Most providers that offer basic webspace solutions don't accomodate this.

Answer (score 0):

Are you saying you don't have command line access to the server, or that you can't use svn+ssh to access your Subversion repository?

If you don't have command line access to your server, it'll be difficult to setup anything in order to use Subversion.

Comment: Ok.. :( No I don't have command line access to the server ... nothing I can do?

Comment: @guylabbe.ca If you don't have command line access, you can't start the server with `svnserve` or create repositories on that server.

Talk to the ISP and see if they have something that can help like UberSVN which allows you to create repositories and manage the Subversion server via a webpage. Otherwise, you'll have to find another [hosting site](http://www.svnhostingcomparison.com/).